# animation in CSS3

Tags: css, animation, hover

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>What</title>
<style type="text/css">
#box1
    {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow:  -3px 8px 34px  #808080;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: -8px 5px 5px #888888;
    right: 100px; top:  50px;
    height:  150px;


}
    #box1:hover {

    }

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst
{
0%   { right:100px; top:50px;background: yellow;}

50%  {background:blue; right:700px; top:50px;}

100% { right:100px; top:50px; background: yellow}

}
    #stam {font-size: large;
           background: green;
           width: 100px;
           top: 400px;
           position: absolute;
    }
    #stam:hover { -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s;


    }
</style>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">

<div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="stam">1234567</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my qustion is: 
How can I do (without JS is better) that whan I put the mouse on "stam" div - the "box1" div will move (will do the animation in the code)? 
I added my code (which isn't work).
Wish for help. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want JavaScript then why did you tag it with that?

Comment: I really don't want JS, but if there is no way to do it without JS, so I will do it in JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `#stam` is going to be *after* your `#box1` you can use the `~` selector - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XEZke/1/)

```css
#box1:hover ~ #stam { -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; }​
```

Comment: Thank you! but I mean that whan I put the mouse on "stam" div, *only* the "box1" will move. Is it possible?

Comment: if you want to do it without JS - just change the order of the elements http://jsfiddle.net/XEZke/2/

Comment: Thank you it works perfect! my quastion now is why this code is don't work when I copy it (I copied the css and the HTML to my editor and it doesn't work :( maybe you can know the reason?

Comment: Google chron the newest version

Comment: Wow!!! thank you a lot!!!! you right! 
last quastion: What matter the location of the div on this page?

Answer (score 0):

Without JS you won't be able to do that unless you change the order/structure of your elements.

Here is some jQuery code, that will do some basic animation for you (in Webkit browsers), just chuck it in your HTML before the closing DOM:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#stam').on('mouseover', function(){
        $('#box1').css('-webkit-animation', 'myfirst');
        $('#box1').css('-webkit-animation-duration', '5s');
      })​;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works (http://jsfiddle.net/a8NYk/1/)! but I have 2 quastions: 
1. Why when I put the mouse in the "stam" div in the second time (aftar the one action finished) it doesn't work anymore?
2. Why this code exactly (like this in the top of the comment) don't work?